# Using tycho-p2-repository-plugin to create zip with parent directory

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am using the `tycho-p2-repository-plugin` during the assembly of my target product. The default behavior of its `archive-repository` goal is to create a zip archive of the aggregated p2 repository.

What I want to know is how to include the parent `repository` directory in the zip file? By default, only the contents of the `repository` directory are included. For example, if you have 2 files `a.file` and `b.file` in the `repository` directory, when you open the generated jar, you'd see this

```
a.file 
b.file
```

However, what I want is the `repository` directory itself to be the first layer in the zip, and if you drill down into it, you'd see the others, like this:

```
repository/
   -> a.file
   -> b.file
```

How can I get `tycho-p2-repository-plugin` to do this?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the tycho-p2-repository-plugin does not allow to customize the layout of the produced zip file.

We had a similar use case where we had to create a WAR file from the bundles of the p2 repository and used the `maven-assembly-plugin` therefore.

Here is what we specified in our `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
    <finalName>my-repo</finalName>
    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>verify</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And here is how the `assembly.xml` could look like:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">  <id>com.diwoblood.war</id>
  <formats>
    <format>war</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}/target/repository/</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/repository</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: @java_code_mongrel Glad that you could solve your problem. I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.